# Trouble running Pi NoIR camera board at documented speeds

Tags: performance, raspicam

The Pi camera board is [described](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1567) as running HD video at 30fps or 0.033spf.  I'm using the picamera python module (the only API I could find) and trying to implement [the client example](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.5/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream).  At less than HD resolution, when I profile **only** the `camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg')` function on a B+, I get ~0.1spf.  How do I get a reasonable frame rate at low resolution (let alone the frame rates and resolutions described).

In case it matters, the ultimate goal is to stream video frame-by-frame (not h.264) from the Pi.

Comment: really minor point but are you running a terminal in X or running this directly from the console? I found hardware control can slow down dramatically when X is running.

Comment: @rob no I'm sshing without X